# Help identifying LEGO set

Tags: set-identification

Anyone recognizes these parts?

[image]

I have a LEGO set with no instructions and no box and I’m trying to see what set it is so I can download the instructions.

Comment: This is basically a bag of random parts. I don't think we'll be able to help here since these  come from multiple sets.

Comment: Thanks.  You are right.  I had purchased set 10228 from amazon.  Had it in storage for some months and decided to put it together.  Inside the box there were no instructions and a bunch of bags - later realized all taped - with pieces of LEGO that were definitely not 10228...I was trying to if they were from any specific set but they are just random pieces in bags...total fraud...anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Alex that it's not from one set. According to BrickLink, the [torso](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0615c01) only appears in Atlantis sets, but that rock panel isn't in any Atlantis sets in [DkBlGrey](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6083&colorID=85&in=A)  or [DkGrey](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6083&colorID=10&in=A)

Comment: In addition, the yellow hull piece can only be found in two Alpha team sets [#4794](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?S=4794-1) and [#4792](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?S=4792-1)